# WP populate select dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, select, html-select

I have two html selects with data from WordPress:

a) select list with cities

```
    <?php
      $args = array( 'child_of' => 50, 'meta_key' => 'E-mail' );
      $pages = get_pages( $args );
      echo '<select id="towns" name="towns">';
      echo '<option value="" selected="selected">Please choose a town...</option>';

      foreach($pages as $post) {
        $page_id = get_the_ID();
        $page_meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'E-mail',true); 
        $page_title = get_the_title($ID);
        echo '<option value="' . $page_meta .'">'. $page_title . '</option>';
      }
      echo '</select>';
    ?>
```

b) select list with street names

```
    <?php
      //$page_id = 62;
      echo '<select id="streets" streets="kierunki">';
      echo '<option value="" selected="selected">Please choose a street</option>';
      $tags = wp_get_post_tags($page_id);

      foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        echo '<option value="' . $tag->name . '">'. $tag->name . '</option>';
      }
      echo '</select>';
      }
    ?>
```

Is it possible to pass value of $page_id to second select so when I choose for example first option in first select dropdown, second select list will appear with corresponding streets?

Comment: You will either have to submit the form and use the `$page_id` in the newly generated form or use jQuery/AJAX to generate the second `select` once a choice has been made for the first `select`.

Comment: According to second solution - how to connect genereated data from second select with jQuery/AJAX?

Comment: Use an `$(#towns).change` function to get the selected town. Then use an `AJAX` call to retrieve the `$tags` you need. Then let jQuery output the HTML for the second `select`.

Comment: Ok, but how transfer with jQuery selected $page_id variable to second select?

Comment: Sorry, this is not a tutorial, workthrough forum. Find some information on those topics, put some code together. If you get stuck submit a new question supplying the code you tried.

Comment: I don't want a tutorial :) I am just curious how to pass variable by jQuery to php echo generated select :)

Comment: That is not how it is done. The jQuery will take care of things, not PHP. You have to adjust your logic.